# Get id attribute from a node in nodelist

Tags: javascript, html

I have currently got a nodelist by using the document.getElementsByClassName method in javascript. I then check if the first node has any children and if not I would return a document.getElementById with that nodes ID.  I am unsure of how to get the ID from the node list.

```
 var columns = document.getElementsByClassName('.col-md-4.column');

if (countChildren(columns[0].childNodes) == 0) {
    return document.getElementById(columns[0].) //not sure what goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a DOM node, it has an `id` property, you can't use `getElementById` to get that property

```
var columns = document.querySelectorAll('.col-md-4.column');

if ( countChildren(columns[0].childNodes) == 0 ) {
    return columns[0].id;
}
```

Note that `getElementsByClassName` takes the classes without the period, but for better support you might as well use `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1):

Not surprisingly, it's `.id`:

```
return document.getElementById(columns[0].id);
```

But more importantly, you already *have* a reference to the node - don't query the DOM for it:

```
return columns[0];
```